# Dynamic name generation with ASP.net MVC template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Lets say I have...

```
@Html.EditorFor(i => i.Date)
```

... and I have a template defined for items of type DateTime. In my template I have...

```
<input type="text" name="???" />
```

Given that the template only receives a DateTime instance, how can one have the template dynamically generate the name of the form field based on the original Model property name being assigned to the template?

Otherwise, upon post back, the model binder won't be able to match up the value from the template with the 'Date' property assigned to it!

Cheers, Ian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could in turn use a Html.TextBox instead of writing out the input tag yourself and it would handle it for you:

```
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new {@class = "date"})
```

Leave the name empty and it will automatically get populated for you. If you want to explicitly write out the HTML tags yourself though, I think that you can get the name with this:

```
<input type="text" name="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.DataTypeName" />
```